# Settimeout in next js/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
let i = 0

function pollDOM() {     
  console.log(i)

  i++

  setTimeout(pollDOM, 3000) // try again in 300 milliseconds
}

pollDOM()
```

The above function use to run every 3 second, output is like:

```
1 

// wait 3 seconds

2 

// wait 3 seconds

3 

// wait 3 seconds

4 

// wait 3 seconds, and so on...
```

But in Next.js, it produces a result as:

```
1
2 

// wait for 3 seconds

3
4

// wait for 3 seconds

5
6

// wait for 3 seconds, and so on...
```

Why it is produced this way, two numbers together?

How can I achieve that that I am achieving in normal JavaScript?

Comment: what do you mean by `in Next.js` ? Can you show us your Component ? Without more information about your code, it's really difficult to help you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bacause when your component is rendered for a second time you're adding the `setTimeout` again. You have to clear your timeout and use `useEffect` to set it only once, when the component is crated. Also, use `setInteval` instead of `setTimeout` when you have to repeat something every x seconds. Try:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let i = 0;

  function pollDOM() {
    console.log(i);
    i++;
  }
  
  const interval = setInterval(pollDOM, 3000);
  
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [])
```